# Commercial or Open Source Java Swing rule/predicate editor widget?

Tags: java, swing

Are there any commercial or open source Java Swing widgets that implement a rule/predicate editor UI? As an example of what I'm looking for, this image shows Cocoa's (excellent) [`NSPredicateEditor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSPredicateEditor_class/Reference/NSPredicateEditor.html) UI for editing a predicate expression:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find any either, probably because there's no standard predicate package in Java.  However, there is the [Google predicate class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955043/predicate-in-java/2955081#2955081) (although it's so simple that you could simply write one yourself).  Depending on the level of complexity you require, I'd happily create one for you for a bounty commission.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently built something that does pretty much this for my application. It's somewhat application specific, but I think it should be possible to make it application agnostic. This is a screenshot of what I built:
[image]

In my scratching about, I didn't come across anything pre-built that would give me this "for free". But I could just be awful at finding such things.

Comment: this looks very close to what I'm after. Would you be willing to share the code (free or commercial license)?

Comment: @Barry Somehow I missed your reply - didn't receive a notification. I'd be willing to share the code. How can I get in contact? I couldn't see any way of privately emailing you outside this site?

Comment: my profile (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2140/barry-wark) has an email address. Or dm me, @barryjwark.

Comment: Sorry, been away. I see no email address on your profile (maybe it's hidden?) And I'm not sure what "dm"ing is... I don't see anything on my StackOverflow pages that would allow me to do that.

Comment: @Gabriel Can you email me at randall.h.wood@alexandriasoftware.com about possibly reusing your predicate editor code in an open source (GPL) project?

Answer (score 0):

We built our own and are releasing it under the BSD license. Code is available at https://github.com/physion/java-predicate-editor