# Subset List of Objects based on matching values

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a situation as described below.

I do have Java Bean named `Document` and it has various properties. One property is

```
String documentStatus
```

and  I do have `List<Document> documentList`. Then I do have `List<String> statusList`.

Now, I want a list of all those documents whose `documentStatus` are matching with given `statusList`.

One solution is to iterate `documentList` and match value using `statusList.contains(document.getStatus())`.

Secondly, [Predicates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955043/predicate-in-java)

Apart from this can anyone have any ideas ?

Any Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You already have two possibilities which both provide a perfectly good solution. Why are you looking for other alternatives? Knowing this, would help in providing the answer you're looking for.

Comment: As you show in your link, I would use the Predicates of the Google Guava library.

Comment: Indeed, the best, clearest approach is using the Guava library and do a Lists.filter(l, predicate);

Comment: Think of copying your `statusList` into a set. Sets may provide O(1) implementations of `contains`, which might be significant when using `contains` in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use contains method in list. Something like

```
for(Document doc:documentList){
if(statusList.contains(doc.getDocumentStatus()))
newDocList.add(doc)
}
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for this..I have mentioned in the post I want to get any other best solution. If feasible, else I am using this only.

Comment: For Now.. I am accepting your answer as Correct. As I was already using this one.