# Filtering a List in Java

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming

In Haskell, I can do

```
filter pred list
```

To create a new list with elements of `list` for which the function `pred` is true. Does the Java API have something similar for `java.util.List` or other collections? I haven't been able to find anything in the API docs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955043/predicate-in-java

Comment: @DarthVader "Disclaimer: If you haven't figured it out, the pic isn't really me." (on their profile) Sad day to be a nerd.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you maybe able to see from [Java doc for List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).  There is no filter for core API.

I would just iterate through the list and pull whatever you need into a new list.

Comment: That's what I am doing for now. This seems like a common enough operation that it would be nice to just write the predicate to pass to a method which has a boiler-plate loop. I'll probably check out Guava as suggested by @PaulBellora

Answer (score 5):

The core API does not, but [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has [`Collections2.filter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29), which takes a `Collection` and [`Predicate`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) and returns a *view* of the filtered elements (which you are free to copy into a new `List`).

Comment: That's so sad...but not entirely unexpected. I was just hoping that I missed something in the API docs.

Comment: Java (at least as of JDK7) is not a functional programming language, and (at least usually) doesn't pretend to be one.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Not being a functional programming language doesn't mean it shouldn't provide useful utilities on basic data types. The need for a filtering operation has little to do with functional programming.

Comment: No, but the use of a filtering operation has to do with the style of functional programming.  A normal imperative approach would be just to copy the satisfying elements into a new list, without a predicate object at all.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Which is a common operation that can easily be extracted into a common library implementation. Your contention is akin to saying that a language like C has no need to implement string searching in its standard library, because `my_string.search(substring)` is OO style and C isn't an OO language. You can still implement a searching operation in a procedural style, and you can implement a list filtering operation in an OO style.