# Search an object in a List with many object's attributes

Tags: java, list, predicates

I have this `List<MyObject> list`.

`MyObject` looks like this :

```
public class MyObject {

    String typeOfObject;

    Integer anInteger;

    Integer value;
}
```

How to get the object(s) from `list` where `typeOfObject = "objectA"` and `anInteger = 1` ?

My goal is to set many variables with `value` of `MyObject`.

I looked at `Predicate`, but it seems that I can base my search condition only on one attribute ?

Comment: If `Predicate` works for one attribute, how about chaining Predicates? Also, what exactly have you tried, `stream().filter(...)`?

Comment: what about going through the list and getting what you need?

Comment: @tobias_k Do you have an exemple please ?

Comment: This one may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955043/predicate-in-java

Comment: Is this about Guava's `Predicate` or Java8's `Predicate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predicates can do exactly what you want and can work on as many attributes as you want them to. You just need to implement the evaluate() method with whatever criteria you want to test against.

```
public class MyPredicate implements Predicate {
    private String testId;  
    private String otherId;

    public MyPredicate(String testId,String otherId) {
        this.testId = testId;
        this.otherId = otherId;
    }

    public boolean evaluate( Object obj ) {
        boolean match = false;
        if( obj instanceof MyObject ) {
            if( testId.equalsIgnoreCase( ((MyObject)obj).getId())
            && otherId.equalsIgnoreCase( ((MyObject)obj).getOtherId()) ) {
                match = true;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
}
```

So in your specific case, the evaluate method would look something like:

```
    public boolean evaluate( Object obj ) {
        boolean match = false;
        if( obj instanceof MyObject ) {
            if( "objectA".equals( ((MyObject)obj).typeOfObject ) 
            && 1 == ((MyObject)obj).anInteger ) {
                match = true;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` to accomplish that refer [this](http://javapapers.com/core-java/hashcode-and-equals-methods-override/) link to accomplish that.

Comment: This should be the right and clean way to do this if you want to avoid iterating over your list each time you want to get an element.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you can use `filter` to get the elements matching your criteria, e.g. using a lambda expression. You can also implement a custom `Predicate` and use that in `filter`

```
List<MyObject> objects = Arrays.asList(
        new MyObject("foo", 1, 42), 
        new MyObject("foo", 3, 23), 
        new MyObject("bar", 3, 42), 
        new MyObject("foo", 4,  42));
List<MyObject> filtered = objects.stream()
        .filter(o -> o.typeOfObject.equals("foo") && o.value == 42)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(filtered);
```

Output is `[(foo,1,42), (foo,4,42)]`, using this test class:

```
class MyObject {
    String typeOfObject;
    Integer anInteger;
    Integer value;
    public MyObject(String type, int i, int v) {
        this.typeOfObject = type;
        this.anInteger = i;
        this.value = v;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%s,%d,%d)", typeOfObject, anInteger, value);
    };
}
```