# Get reverse of predicate when Filtering?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I know the basics of predicates and understand below code copied from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955043/predicate-in-java)

```
Predicate<Integer> isEven = new Predicate<Integer>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(Integer number) {
        return (number % 2) == 0;
    }               
};
Iterable<Integer> evenNumbers = Iterables.filter(numbers, isEven);
```

But is it possible to get an iterable for the items that did not match the predicate (without changing the predicate code)?

Comment: You could create a negation predicate, namely,  `not isEven`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Predicates#not(Predicate)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#not%28com.google.common.base.Predicate%29).

```
Iterable<Integer> oddNumbers = Iterables.filter(numbers, Predicates.not(isEven));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
removeIf(Iterable, Predicate) -->   Removes all elements satisfying the predicate, using the Iterator.remove() method.  

Iterators.removeIf(Iterator, Predicate)
```

Can find more information [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#removeIf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29).